# Flagging a user

Tags: discussion, flagging

I was reviewing some posts today and found one new user posted 7 answers in an hour, 2 on the same question on mostly already answered questions.

https://music.stackexchange.com/users/8740/user8740

Some of his posts were fine, but a good number of them are either bad answers or not answers at all. I flagged those posts, but is there a better practice for flagging new users who make a lot of questionable posts?

Comment: please guys check his answers http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/541/how-many-hours-of-practice-total-are-typical-for-different-piano-grades/14265#14265 and http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/14053/why-do-melodies-have-harmonies/14266#14266 someone should delete his account as he no longer wishes to contribute and he's acting like babies

Comment: I flagged him already when I saw he posted again.

Comment: He has been deleted and I would like to say one more thing in general about this topic. This site is suppose to be about a community not only answering each other's questions, but gathering around a common topic and sharing knowledge about it to everyone who wants to know. This person not only disrespected and belligerent the community, but tried to undermine the community even in the end saying "I'm an expert. I don't need this site.". I don't care if he was an expert or not he was toxic to the community and anyone like that should not be apart of this community.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe flagging a post of his for moderation attention and mentioning the problem there will work

Comment: This is the right way to do it.  Only posts can be flagged, not users, and we appreciate any explanation.

Answer (score 4):

New users often get "flagged" automatically so higher-rep users can guide them and welcome them to the site. In this case, moderator action was required and taken.

Comment: But only 2 of his first 7 posts were flagged and they were flagged by the late answer review.